# How to put a small text above a button for android?

Tags: android

I am tring to make a calculator application. I want to set a small text above some of my buttons. I am using a LinearLayout to place the buttons - 5 on each row. Should I use a small TextView above the buttons or is there any attribute for the button that I can use? But how do I ensure that the text is right above each button in that case?

Comment: set text for the button itself.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `LinearLayout` for the 5 buttons, each element should be another `LinearLayout`, this time vertical, and then use a `TextView` for the text, followed by a `Button` for the button.

```
<LinearView orientation='horizontal'>
    <LinearView orientation='vertical'>
        <TextView />
        <Button />
    </LinearView>
    <LinearView orientation='vertical'>
        ...
    </LinearView>
    ...
</LinearView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and use the properties of `android:layout_below=` and/or `android:layout_above=`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some Text" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    android:text="This Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or you could add another vertical linear layout for every button, in which you place the textview and button.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:text=button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```